# Button being shown as [object Object] in dynamic table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a to do list using jquery and want to add a delete button to my table.  When the delete button is displayed in the table, it simply says [object Object].  Can anyone help with this?  Below is my jQuery and HTML.  The last line of my jQuery is where I add the delete button.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //Add the importance level to the first column of the to do table
  $("#submit-button").on("click", function addTask() {
    var taskToDo = $("#comment").val();
    var newRow = $("<tr>");
    var newTd = $("<td>");
    var deleteBtn = $("<button>").addClass("btn btn-danger").append("X");

    //Append the importance ranking to the table
    if($('#vimp').is(':checked'))
      alert("Your task is very important")
      newRow.append("<td>X</td>");
      /*var bullet = $("&bull;").css("color","red");
      $("#to-do-list").append(newRow);
        newRow.append('<td>'+bullet+'</td>');*/

    if($('#simp').is(':checked'))
      alert("Your task is somewhat important")

    if($('#canwait').is(':checked'))
      alert("Your task can wait")
  
    //Append the task to the table
    $("#to-do-list").append(newRow);
      //newRow.append("<td>X</td>");
      newRow.append('<td>'+taskToDo+'</td>');
      newRow.append('<td>'+deleteBtn+'</td>');

  });

});
```

```html
      <table class="table table-striped table-responsive table-hover" id="col-width">
        <col width="30px">
        <col width="400px">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <td>Importance</td>
            <td>Task</td>
            <td>Delete button</td>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="to-do-list">
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Because you are concatenating an object with a string. Try to append the html of the delete button, or, try to append a cell to the row and the button to the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`deleteBtn` is a jQuery object, but `+` operator in `'<td>'+deleteBtn+'</td>'` expects a string, hence the object is automatically converted to its string representation.

To fix the problem, you need to append the `td` first, and then append the button to the `td`, for example like this:

```
newRow.append('<td>').find('td').last().append(deleteBtn);
```

Comment: Thank you! My issue with this method is that when I do this the delete button is being added after an empty <td> tag, and not into the actual tag. Is there a different method I can use?

Comment: @wariofan1 Sorry, my bad. Confused with native `appendChild` which returns the appended element. I've fixed the code.